# How to debug boost with source from Qt creator

Tags: qt-creator

I wish to debug an ugly crash in a C++ command-line tool.  It uses, among other things, boost and crashes over there for no obvious reason.  I wish to be able to debug the program in the boost source file.

The program is linked against an automatically downloaded library that has debug symbols.  I'm on mac os x, The library file is located at `/opt/alg/boost-1.60.0-v2-c++11/libs/libboost_program_options-mt.a`.  Yet the debugger of qt creator reports the source file to obey the source structure under directory `/private/tmp/boost-20160422-2234-7rfp6t/boost_1_60_0`, which does not exist.

In Preferences->Debugger->Source path mappings, I've set both those path to target the root directory of the source I've downloaded at `/opt/alg/boost-1.60.0-v2-c++11/src`, yet I still cannot see the source file and I can only see the dissambled executable.

Comment: Please try Valgrind for weird memory errors, since it highlight the root of cause which is probably in your code.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that too.  But if you know how to display external sources in QtCreator, pleas tell anyway !

Comment: Valgrind didn't work out.  I have a few errors with the dynamic loader dyld, that I can obtain also with commands that do not crash, but valgrind report nothing different between the command that crashes and the ones that don't (it hangs indefinitely with any command at some point, maybe I'm missing some data).  I'd really like to debug boost if possible.

Comment: If Qt Creator's configuration don't work, try directly working with gdb.

Comment: On mac I have lldb... However, it doesn't work either...  I'm upgrading the question for lldb.